# Automake include file only if it exists

Tags: automake

I'm trying to build a project that supports easily building 'stripped-down' distributions with undesired features removed.  The project uses automake and is structured with potentially removable features in their own feature.am files that are included in the top-level Makefile.am file as

```
include feature.am
```

The problem is, if you remove a feature (and its feature.am file), autoreconf fails with

```
automake: error: cannot open < feature.am: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to simply ignore this error and continue?  I tried using

```
-include feature.am
```

like GNU make does, but this ends up simply copying that line into the Makefile.in file (and thus the Makefile), rather than having automake read it.

Comment: how about `touch`ing all the required files before running `automake`? this way they will always be present (but sometimes empty)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because of the way `automake` works (which has next to nothing to do with how `make` includes files by itself.)

You *can* use `AM_CONDITIONAL` and autoconf's `AC_ARG_ENABLE` to build or not build the components that you don't want built. If you would like to have separate tarballs, that's more complicated and I would suggest you just ship separate packages for those features.